# Shnayim Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

It seems that the new site's engine doesn't like the similarity of this question to previous questions in this series. I guess I'll have to get a little more creative ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a non-leap year, *Shavuot* is the 242nd day in the year if *Heshvan* is *Haser* (has 29 days) and *Kislev* is whole (has 30 days):

*Tishrei* - 30 days each
*Heshvan*, *Kislev* - 59 days together
*Tevet* - 29 days
*Shvat* - 30 days
*Adar* - 29 days
*Nisan* - 30 days
*Iyar* - 29 days 
*Sivan* - 6 days (Shavout is on the 6th day of *Sivan*)

Answer (score 3):

[United Nations Security Council Resolution 242.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_242)

Comment: Not such an on-topic answer, but I've done worse.

Answer (score 3):

> To look at the figures another way, for every thousand Soviet citizens attending higher educational institutions in the late 1950s, there were... two-hundred-forty-two Jews.

— Samuel A. Oppenheim, "Jew", in, James S. Olson, editor, [*An Ethnohistorical Dictionary of the Russian and Soviet Empires*](http://books.google.com/books?id=CquTz6ps5YgC&pg=PA323&dq=forty), ISBN 0313274975, 1994, page 323.

Answer (score 1):

> רָאשִׁים לְאָבוֹת מָאתַיִם אַרְבָּעִים וּשְׁנָיִם
>
> heads of [certain] households [of *kohanim in Y'rushalayim*] were 242

—[*N'chemya* 11:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16518#v=13)